# How to properly write utf8 IPTC metadata with python library IPTCInfo?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

After generating a JPEG thumbnail file with [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), I would like to use [IPTCInfo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPTCInfo/) in order to write IPTC metadata containing french characters with accents. I was thinking about using UTF8 character encoding.

So I tried the following:

```
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True, inp_charset='utf8')
info.data['credit'] = some_unicode_string
info.saveAs(output_file)
```

and many other variations:

```
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True)
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True, inp_charset='utf8')
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True, inp_charset='utf_8')
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True, inp_charset='utf8', out_charset='utf8')
info = IPTCInfo(input_file, force=True, inp_charset='utf_8', out_charset='utf_8')
...
```

While reading with IPTCInfo the metadata written by IPTCInfo preserves the unicode python string, I always find weird characters when trying to read with other piece of software: OSX file information, Exiftools, PhotoShop, ViewNX2.
So what is the right way to write unicode with IPTCInfo and produce a standard compliant file understandable by all software?

Comment: Is there an IPTC tag "CodedCharacterSet" in the resulting files?

Comment: It does not seem so. Exiftool command "exiftool -codedCharacterSet my_file.jpg" returns nothing. However, for information, I don't always have a CodedCharacterSet with software that produce nice formated accents. For example, ViewNX2 returns nothing and Photoshop returns "Coded Character Set             : UTF8" but both present accents nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Something related to your question. Coming from the [IPTC forum](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/iptc-photometadata/conversations/messages/303)

> - Using the XMP packet makes things quite easy: UTF-8 is the default character set. Thus you can use and even mix different characters sets and scripts.
> - The IPTC IIM header is a bit more tricky: it includes a field to indicate which character set has been used for textual fields (for the IIM experts: this is dataset 1:90) but unfortunately this field has not been used by a vast majority of imaging software and only in most recent years some of them are using it.

Also in the [IPTC EnvelopeRecord Tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/IPTC.html), you will find:

> `90   CodedCharacterSet   string[0,32]!`
>
> (values are entered in the form "ESC X Y[, ...]". The escape sequence for UTF-8 character coding is "ESC % G", but this is displayed as "UTF8" for convenience. Either string may be used when writing. The value of this tag affects the decoding of string values in the Application and NewsPhoto records. This tag is marked as "unsafe" to prevent it from being copied by default in a group operation because existing tags in the destination image may use a different encoding. When creating a new IPTC record from scratch, it is suggested that this be set to "UTF8" if special characters are a possibility)

See also [-charset CHARSET](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q10)

> Certain meta information formats allow coded character sets other than plain ASCII. When reading, most known encodings are converted to the external character set according to the exiftool "-charset CHARSET" or -L option, or to UTF‑8 by default. When writing, the inverse conversion is performed. Alternatively, special characters may be converted to/from HTML character entities with the -E option.

Though the [comment in the code of IPTCInfo](https://bitbucket.org/gthomas/iptcinfo/src/0dc2b4e3de4ec3708002fcd1b23b9aed5df3b237/iptcinfo.py?at=default#cl-561) implementation of IPTC is not very encouraging, but there is still a [dictionary of encoding](https://bitbucket.org/gthomas/iptcinfo/src/0dc2b4e3de4ec3708002fcd1b23b9aed5df3b237/iptcinfo.py?at=default#cl-930) in the code which gives more clues.

In your code example which seems to be correct, you are giving. :)

`info.data['credit'] = some_unicode_string`

What do you call some_unicode_string? Are you sure it's a utf-8 string (!= unicode).